# Rails: activeadmin overriding create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, inherited-resources

I have an activeadmin resource which has a belongs_to :user relationship.

When I create a new Instance of the model in active admin, I want to associate the currently logged in user as the user who created the instance (pretty standard stuff I'd imagine).

So... I got it working with:

```
controller do
  def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    @item.user = current_curator
    super
  end 
end
```

However ;)  I'm just wondering how this works?  I just hoped that assigning the @item variable the user and then calling super would work (and it does).  I also started looking through the gem but couldn't see how it was actually working.

Any pointers would be great.  I'm assuming this is something that InheritedResources gives you?

Thanks!

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I ran into a similar situation where I didn't really need to completely override the create method. I really only wanted to inject properties before save, and only on create; very similar to your example. After reading through the ActiveAdmin source, I determined that I could use `before_create` to do what I needed:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do
  before_create do |product|
    product.creator = current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Just want to mention that `before_save` also works if you need to handle the update case as well.

Answer (score 16):

Another option:

```
def create
  params[:item].merge!({ user_id: current_curator.id })
  create!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right active admin use `InheritedResources`, all other tools you can see on the end of the [page](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin).

Comment: Damn, upon re-reading the docs properly (apologies for anyone else reading this)... I should have just called create! instead of super above.  Though I think it'll do the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

As per the AA [source code](https://github.com/activeadmin/active_admin/blob/d25e8d09f723fc3ae55a21cd22bc7c6466ba32f8/spec/unit/resource_controller_spec.rb#L92) this worked for me:

```
controller do
  def call_before_create(offer)
  end
end
```

Comment: You pulled this from the tests. It is only there as a mockup. This only works if you create add a `call_before_create` method in your registered resource. Here you can see where they make the `call_before_create` method as a muckup for testing: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/d25e8d09f723fc3ae55a21cd22bc7c6466ba32f8/spec/unit/resource_controller_spec.rb#L58-L79