# Is it possible to have a join table with only two primary keys when using Rails ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I can edit a join table in ActiveAdmin, only if the join table has one, and only one, primary key (id).

If I try to design a join table with only two fields (primary key on both), ActiveAdmin returns a NilClass error when I attempt to add a new record : `undefined method 'humanize' for nil:NilClass`.

model :

```
class IngredientProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

ingredient_products fields :

```
product_id --> primary key, nn, integer
ingredient_id --> primary key, nn, integer
```

That doesn't work.  My table "ingredient_products" must be designed this way :

```
id --> primary key, nn, integer
product_id --> integer
ingredient_id --> integer
```

to allow me to edit or add record with ActiveAdmin.

Do you know if ActiveAdmin support join tables that have only two fields, both used to define the primary key ?

My project : MySql, Rails 4.0.1 with ActiveRecord and ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre

Comment: Really I don't think that can be a good idea to add rows to your IngredientProduct table manually. Maybe you can have a good reason, but I think that should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: I'm not an expert with ActiveAdmin, you suggest that the association between Ingredients and Products should be done in Products or Ingredients form ? (If so, how you do that?)

Comment: That's what I meant. So you have a Products form, and an Ingredients form, you can add to each one a non-required field for the other Id, and then override the create method for each one, and that pretty much all. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675765/rails-activeadmin-overriding-create-action and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524012/insert-a-non-input-row-into-a-formtasic-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a join table without an `id` column, you'll want to omit the model file entirely (IngredientProduct in this case) and use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` on both ends. ActiveAdmin appears to be able to edit habtm associations:

http://www.mickgardner.com/2012/12/habtm-and-activeadmin-forms.html

Answer (score 2):

The `ID` is actually the the Primary Key in this situation, whereas `product_id` and `ingredient_id` are foreign keys, as they are they keys that reference the primary key of another table.  A Primary Key is important because there should only be one.  However, you can have the combination of your two foreign keys be unique, by adding database constraints.

in a migration, do this:

```
add_index :ingredient_products, [:product_id, :ingredient_id], unique: true
```

If you are intent on using a composite primary key, this gem will do the trick I believe.

https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

Comment: As far as I know you can have more than one column to "make" your primary key : a primary key is a combination of columns which uniquely specify a row. I'm sure your solution is fine (thanks), but changing the table structure is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You may have a composite primary key(I think), but I don't believe it is especially good for performance.  The index for all intents and purposes is the same (since the combination is unique, as a primary key must be), and doesn't change the table structure at all.  It just adds the index to boost performance.  May I enquire for what reason's you require a composite primary key?

Comment: Here is some more info as to what you are looking for. https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys.  If this is sufficient I'd be much obliged if you could accept the answer. If you need any more information let me know.